# Installing Sun Java on Fedora 14

Tags: java, fedora

How do you install Sun Java on Fedora 14, instead of the default OpenJDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to [**http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Download JDK
3. Choose **Linux x64** for Platform
4. Download the RPM **`jdk-6u23-linux-x64-rpm.bin`**
5. `sudo sh jdk-6u23-linux-x64-rpm.bin`
6. `sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/default/bin/java 20000`

Sanity check:

```
[root@server ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Do I need to uninstall gcj, if so what is the best method?

Comment: No need as far as I know. Why should gcj be a problem?